# How to print object data in javascript

Tags: javascript, object

I have the following object data:

```
var response = {
    "response": {
        "numFound": 7945,
        "docs": [{
            "description": "target",
            "url": "target",
            "id": "269653",
            "score": 6.9186745
        },
        {
            "description": "Target Kent",
            "url": "Target_Kent",
            "id": "37275",
            "score": 4.3241715
        }]
    },
    "highlighting": {
        "269653": {
            "description": ["<em>target</em>"]
        },
        "37275": {
            "description": ["<em>Target</em> Kent"]
        }
    }
};
```

I can use `response.response.docs[0].description` to print out `"target"`. But I don't know how to print out `"<em>target</em>"`. Thanks.

Comment: Please clarify your question. You said you can get it to print "target" but you don't know how to print "target"?

Comment: Question is not clear enough to be solved please edit and make things bit clear

Answer (score 1):

```
response.highlighting[269653].description[0]
```

**Try it:** http://jsfiddle.net/9QFAM/

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you need to keep the reference to docs[0] or whichever other object reference:

```
response.highlighting[response.response.docs[0].id].description[0]
```